# Why does reinstalling a package only take a short time the second time?

Tags: installation, package-management

Let's say I first install some package using `apt-get`, for example:

`apt-get install some-package`

Then I remove this package using:

`apt-get remove some-package`

Now I try to install that same package again but the install process finishes very quickly.

Why is that? Does `apt-get` save downloaded files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [`apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) is caching downloaded packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/`.

If you want to install a package `apt-get` first looks up the cache and only downloads the package again if it couldn't find that package in the cache.

To empty the cache you have to issue a `apt-get clean`.

Comment: I was going to say because apt-get packages don't die they multiply. But I guess your answer is more technically accurate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yap, the packages are cached after installing :)

/var/cache/apt/....